# Connecting Mongoose Schema to one another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have an existing schema for a user profile that looks like:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: { type: String },
  name: {
    first: { type: String, required: true },
    last: { type: String, required: true }
  }
});
```

My question is: can I create another schema which holds properties for event registration (such as type of pass the user is paying for, address, contact number, etc.) specific info instead and have it connect to the `userSchema`? Or would it be more effective to throw all of that info into the `userSchema`?

Example Registration schema:

```
const registrationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  pass: { type: String },
  address: { type: String },
  phone: { type: String },
  paid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  shirt: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases

1. The relation between entities is 1:1 (Your case?) - Put them in the same schema. We're lucky not to use relational db.
2. The relation is 1:N but there will be a predictable and not large amount of children per parent - also put them in the same schema.

Examples of 2:

a. user roles.

b. user visited countries.

3. the relation is 1:N and there can be any number of children per parent and it is not predictable - Use a different schema.

examples of 3:

a. user orders.

b. user location history.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful explanation. For the amount of children in any given property (probably less than 6) I will restrict myself to just the one schema.